# Filter list elements with hot chocolate (v13) GraphQL

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm using hot chocolate type extension
and trying to filter list elements.
here are my classes:

```
public class A
{
    public B b { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public string name {  get; set; }
    public List<C> c { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public bool isNew { get; set; }
}
```

query:

```
[UseFiltering]
public async Task<IQueryable<A>> GetA([Service] ISender sender)
{
    return await sender.Send(new GetAQuery());
}
```

I'm trying to filter the list elements by "isNew" (I want to be able to get only the elements with isNew = true )
the default list filters are "any, none, all, some",
is there an option to add a 'where' filter to the schema definition?
[image]

I know I can extend the B object:

```
[ExtendObjectType(typeof(B))]
public class BResolver
{
    public List<C> NewC([Parent] B b)
        => b.c.Where(el=>el.isNew).ToList();
}
```

but that's not what I'm looking for,
I don't want to add fields, I want to filter on the existing field

Comment: [filtering](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/filtering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use **some** keyword in **where** expression.
You can filter high-level elements by child element fields like this:

```
query {
  a(where: { b: { c: { some: { isNew: { eq: true } } } } }) {
    b {
      name
      c {
        isNew
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need filter nested elements, you need to add **[UseFiltering()]** attribute:

```
public class A
{
    public B b { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    [UseFiltering()] // This row
    public List<C> c { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public bool isNew { get; set; }
}
```

and filter only nested objects like this:

```
query {
  a {
    b {
      name
      c(where: { isNew: { eq: true } }) {
        isNew
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: using the "some" keyword is not what I need, it will return all the items that their list contain at least one isNew=true. but your second solution (adding the  [UseFiltering()] attribute) works. thank you!!!!